# MUi datagrid rows not popuplating

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I'm encountering an issue that I'm struggling to get to the bottom of. I am utilizing the Material UI Datagrids, but I cannot seem to get it to populate with data, and I cannot understand why. When I look at my Component profiler, I can see the data I'm trying to display is there, so I cannot understand why there are no rows.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { DataGrid } from '@mui/x-data-grid';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid'

const columns = [
  { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 70 },
  { field: 'socioid', headerName: 'SocioID', width: 150 },
  { field: 'name', headerName: 'Name', width: 200 },
  { field: 'label', headerName: 'Label', width: 160, },
];


export default function DataTable(props) {


  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(props.users)
    props.users.map((key, value)=>{
      console.log(props.users[value]);
    })

  })

  const detailsRows =
    props.users.map((key, value) => {
      return {
        socioid: props.users[key],
        name: props.users[value].n.SociomapName,
        //name: user.n.SociomapName,
        // label: "label",
      }
    })

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 600, width: '100%' }}>
      <DataGrid 
      autoHeight
      getRowId={() => uuidv4()}
      rows={detailsRows}
        columns={columns} 
        initialState={{
          pagination: {
            paginationModel: { page: 0, pageSize: 10 },
          },
        }}
        pageSizeOptions={[10,30,50]} />
    </div>  
  );
}
```

Comment: what error do you get? what did you use to build react project? is is static or ssr? By the way package json homepage does not affect react at all